# Running javascript when document loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a script that will enable a submit button once a check-box is checked.

I am following an example found here: http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/

I have added the following java-script code to my page but it doesn't seem like the script is executing properly. I do not see any errors in the console however.

```
<!---JQuery Iniialization --->
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Form Code:

```
 <FORM ACTION="signature_action.cfm?ticket_id=#url.ticket_id#&device=pc" METHOD=POST NAME="SigForm">

      <div align="center">
      <h2>STEP 1</h2>
      <strong>Select the type of signature that is being captured:</strong><br />
       <table><tr><td align="left"> 
                            <div id="format">
                            <input name="equipment_dropped_off" type="checkbox" id="check1" value="equipment_dropped_off" />
                            <label for="check1"><span class="style1">Equipment Dropped Off &nbsp; &nbsp; </span></label>
                            <span class="style1">
                            <input name="work" type="checkbox" id="check2" value="work"/>
                            <label for="check2">Work performed &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
                            <input name="payment" id="check3" type="checkbox" value="payment" />
                            <label for="check3">Payment Recieved &nbsp; &nbsp; </label>
                            <input name="equipment_picked_up" id="check4" type="checkbox" value="equipment_picked_up" />
                            <label for="check4">Equipment Picked Up</label>
                            </span><br />
                            <input name="tech_name" type="hidden" value="#url.tech_name#">
                            </div>
                            <input name="hidden" type="hidden" value="#url.tech_name#">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="STEP 4 - SAVE SIGNATURE" disabled>
</form>
```

I am new to javascript and I am strugling a bit. Doesn't this need to run once the DOM is ready? (I am not sure how to do that!)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you include jQuery.js in page? Code shown is dependent on jQuery library. Use browser console (F12) to see what errors are thrown.

Comment: It is running when the DOM is ready - jQuery's `ready()` is a decorator around that, and your code works on my system exactly as you describe it should.

Comment: Yes I included jquery in my page. I updated my post with my jquery reference. @jdphenix - How do I do that? That is where I am lost.

Comment: Okay - Take a look here - http://api.jquery.com/ready/  - All your code is the function that's passed to ready - your code only runs after the DOM is ready because of the `jQuery.ready()` function call. As far as your fiddle - it works like you describe for me.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML.

Comment: So I am confused, is my Javascript that I posted correct then? In my JSfiddle example, onDOMready is chosen. How would that complete <script> tag look in that case? (I just edited my original post to include the HTML form)

Comment: the script looks OK to me.  how is the form being loaded?  e.g. are you loading it dynamically, or is it in the same HTML document as the script?  if the form is being loaded by script or by Ajax call, it's possible that it is being inserted into the DOM after your javascript has run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this article: [How to add onDomReady to my document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196596/how-to-add-ondomready-to-my-document), I put my code inside:

```
window.onload = function() {
//code here
}
```

Comment: `.onload` is _not_ the same as onDomReady, and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13196705/17300) you copy-pasted was downvoted.

Comment: The jQuery way is as the OP uses it: `$(document).ready()` — the basic event it [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). YUI [uses](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#modules) domready and contentready.

Answer (score 0):

The event that must be listened is "change".

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

  checkboxes.on('change', function() {
    submitButt.attr('disabled', !this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: This actually breaks the code and causes the disabled attribute to never be enabled.